# Why is DateTime.MinValue a constant expression, but not DateTime.MaxValue in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have a mammoth method signature as follows:

```
Public Shared Function GetChartData(Optional adHoc As Boolean = True, Optional startIndex As Integer = 0, Optional endIndex As Integer = Int32.MaxValue, _
                                    Optional startTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue, Optional endTime As DateTime = DateTime.MaxValue, _
                                    Optional deviceIds As List(Of Integer) = Nothing) As IEnumerable(Of ChartLinePoint)
```

The compiler only complains about `endTime` and says its default value, 'DateTime.MaxValue' must be a constant expression. It seems quite happy with `startTime`.

Comment: Both are not constants but `Public Shared ReadOnly` fields.

Comment: Aha, thank you. I removed `endTime` and still got the error. Good old 'Nothing' for now.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hm, did you edit that in there? I didn't see if when I looked at it originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are **not** constants but `Public Shared ReadOnly` fields ([evidence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)).

So even `DateTime.MinValue` is not accepted by the compiler as constant expression in an optional parameter:

```
Sub FooMethod(Optional d As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue)
    'COMPILER ERROR '
End Sub
```

But you could use `Nothing` which means default value in VB.NET and `DateTime.MinValue` is the default:

```
Sub FooMethod(Optional d As DateTime = Nothing)
     ' works '
End Sub
```

It's also a viable approach to use a `Nullable(Of DateTime)` instead, all the more if `Date.MinValue` could be a valid value.

```
Sub FooMethod(Optional d As DateTime? = Nothing)
     If d.HasValue Then
         ' use d.Value '
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am now using nullables, with defaults of `Nothing`, and then in the proc if `Nothing`, I set to min or max.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to create const values of arbitrary value (or reference) types in .NET.

Only those types for which C#<sup>1</sup> has literals, allowing initialisation of const fields, can have const values.

---

<sup>1</sup> C# is used to write most of the base class library (BCL).